# SourceTree: how to show commit information panel if once hide?

Tags: ios, git

On one of my machines, I have somehow hidden the panel which shows commit information, such as the commit hash and the full commit message. 
I'm sure it's just a setting somewhere to bring the commit panel back, but I can't find it. Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean as what I suggest makes more changes than juts that tab. Choose the menu View->History View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this in the terminal & restart SourceTree

```
defaults delete com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS "NSSplitView Subview Frames repowindow_LogViewDescSplitter"
```

[Source](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/15282793/sourcetree-how-to-show-commit-information-panel)

Comment: I tried this in Sourcetree's terminal on Windows and it said "bash: defaults: command not found". How do I get this to work on Windows?